# Hibernate 6.1.5.Final unable to determine table reference

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Hello StackOverflow Community,

#### Attempted:

Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7.5 to 3.0.0, which uses Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final

**Entity**

Plant.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Plant {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plant")
    List<Branch> branches;

}
```

Branch.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Branch {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Plant plant;

}
```

VPlantUI.java

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class VPlantUI {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plant")
    List<Branch> branches;
    
    // joins, fields from other tables

}
```

#### Issue:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.UnknownTableReferenceException: Unable to determine TableReference (`plant`) for `ca.demo.model.view.VPlantUI.branches.{fk-target}`
```

#### Question:

I'm attempting to map VPlantUI to a view in the database.

**Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23, Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final** did not have any issue with this type of mapping however **Spring Boot v3.0.0, Spring v6.0.2, Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final** doesn't allow this type of mapping.

What are the alternatives/options to map VPlantUI to Branch?

Comment: I have same problem since migrating spring boot to 3 & hibernate to 6. 
also same problem there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2423#issuecomment-1336430688

Comment: Did you find a solution? Updating to hibernate-core 6.2.0 or higher doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I upgraded to spring-boot-starter-parent:3.1.0 which uses hibernate-core:6.2.2.Final and I have a different error now.

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'ca.demo.model.view.VPlantUI.branches' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'plant' which references the wrong entity type 'ca.demo.model.Plant', expected 'ca.demo.model.view.VPlantUI'

Answer (score 0):

According to this [jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16080) it worked for me with version **6.2.0.Final** of **hibernate-core**